# RABBITMQ_BASE on Windows

Tags: rabbitmq

I am aware that one can set the `RABBITMQ_BASE` enironment variable on Windows to change *where* RabbitMQ stores/finds all its moving bits.

My question is this: Is it recommended that one always set this to a deterministic folder?

I have found that the whole %APPDATA% location seems problematic even if one were to use a specific service account, as opposed to `Local System` and co.

Perhaps I am answering my own question but I'd like to know what the take is on this in the wild.

Comment: `%ProgramData%` is probably a better place as `%APPDATA%` is user specific

Comment: Agreed, but it seems as though RabbitMQ uses the `%AppData%` which is part of my concern. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it happens, I am also researching this very same question.

I have been reading this thread on github which has been very helpful.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/626

In my opinion it is NOT recommended for a service's files to be located under a users account directory. It just shouts wrong to me!

As you suggest, I would set this to a deterministic folder. eg: `D:\RabbitMQBase`.

Incidentally, on that page they talk about adding a step to the installer for the user to set `RABBITMQ_BASE`.  However this has not been done.

Please scroll down to biiiipy's comments where he describes what he does and the batch files he is using. His comments are very valuable.